# Launch a program using sudo

Tags: c, linux, sudo

I want to launch a program using sudo, I have used this command

`sudo './ConnectionManager'`

On a:

```
Distributor ID: ScientificSL
Description:    Scientific Linux SL release 5.5 (Boron)
Release:        5.5
Codename:       Boron
(Like Centos5.5)
```

and it works, but it doesn't work on

```
Distributor ID: Scientific
Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)
Release:        6.4
Codename:       Carbon
```

in the last case I have immediately the following message:
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo './ConnectionManager'

I have check the code and the problem is the instruction `int setpgrp(void)` in ConnectionManager.

ConnectionManager is a program written in C, wich fork a process in order to wait for tcp/ip connnection.

Someone can help me ?

Follow a sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
...
int main()
{

    if (chdir("/opt/informix/server") == -1)
{
  printf("Errore nella directory /opt/informix/server\n");
  getch();  
  exit(1);    
};


    signal(SIGINT, onexit);
    signal(SIGUSR1, RefreshMainWindow);

signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
signal(SIGCLD, SIG_IGN);
setpgrp();

ParentPid = getpid();



/***/
if (LockFile(_true) != _ok)
{     
  exit(1);
}

if (CreateDestroyShm(_true) != _ok)
{   
  exit(1);
}

    ...

    if (LockFile(_false, &sdebug) != _ok)
{   
  exit(1);
}


/***/

init_curses();      
menubar  = subwin(stdscr, 1, MAXCOLS, 0, 0);
main_win = subwin(stdscr, MAXROWS-1, MAXCOLS, 1, 0);
cbreak();           /* immediately acquire each keystroke */
PrintTestata();
draw_menubar(menubar);

/***/



switch (fork())
{
  case 0:
    signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN);
  break;
  default:     

   KeyboardHandler();
}


    void init_curses()
    { 

  putenv("TERM=xterm");

      initscr();
      wresize(stdscr, MAXROWS, MAXCOLS);
      start_color();
      init_pair(1,COLOR_WHITE,COLOR_RED);
      init_pair(2,COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_WHITE);
      init_pair(3, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLUE);
      init_pair(4, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLUE);
      curs_set(0);
      noecho();
      keypad(stdscr,TRUE);
      touchwin(stdscr);
      wrefresh(stdscr);  
  }
```

Comment: If the [`setpgrp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setpgrp.html) function fails, it will return `-1` and set [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html). Have you checked the [error code](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/errno.h.html) in `errno`? You can print the error with e.g. [`perror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/perror.html).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, setpgrp return 0.

Comment: Then it doesn't fail, so the problem must be something else.

Comment: The strange thing is that the code following setpgrp is executed, even if it stops with the message Stopped sudo './ConnectionManager'. If I comment setpgrp all the code is executed.

Comment: Well there is nothing we can do without some serious psychic abilities. You need to show us some code. Please edit your question to include some relevant code, or a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The program if I use setpgrp instruction stops on ncurses instruction intscr. The ncurses version is the same for the 2 hosts

Comment: The stop occurs when I use sudo, setpgrp() and initscr()

Comment: @famedoro - is SELinux installed and enabled on your system?  Use the 'sestatus' command to find out.  I've had unexplainable sudo failures happen due to that.  Such events might be logged in '/var/log/audit'.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your process is not in the sessions foreground process group and despite that tries to read or write to the terminal.

See the "Notes" section in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html and "Jobs and sessions" from http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/.

You could also check in the code `if (tcgetpgrp(STDOUT_FILENO) == getpgid(0))`.  If it is not, you are not in the foreground.

Comment: That was my best guess based on the information available.
You could also try asking in [superuser](http://superuser.com/).